# Promisify node-ftps command

Tags: node.js, ftp, lftp

Im a trying to promisify a [node-ftps](https://github.com/Atinux/node-ftps) function in order to use *async/await*. I am referring to this github [link](https://github.com/Atinux/node-ftps/issues/50#issuecomment-301729338) which explains how it should be done. I came up with the following code but it is still not working.

My promisified function :

```js
const ftpGetFile = async (ftps, source, destination) => {

    console.log(`FTP MGET ${source} => ${destination}`)
    return ftps.raw(`mget -e -O ${destination} ${source}`).exec((error, result) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("ftp fget error", error)
                reject(error)
            } else {
                console.log("ftp fget succss", result)

                resolve(result)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

And how I call it

```js
for (let index = 0; index < listToSync.length; index++) {

    // ....
    await ftpGetFile(ftp, source, destination)
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to return the promise itself, which then resolves in the callback to `exec`:

```js
const ftpGetFile = async (ftps, source, destination) => {
  console.log(`FTP MGET ${source} => ${destination}`)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ftps.raw(`mget -e -O ${destination} ${source}`).exec((error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("ftp fget error", error)
        reject(error)
      } else {
        console.log("ftp fget succss", result)
        resolve(result)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: of course!!!... I think it'time for a walk. Thanks man

Comment: No problem - we've all been there :)